# Custom typegen and using ApiPromise: Property 'unwrap' does not exist on type 'Codec'

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-types

It seems there is a mismatch between autocomplete suggestion return types from an ApiPromise instance and the actual returned type.

I am using `"@polkadot/api": "8.1.1"`. I am writing some typescript tests for some custom api.derive methods for a substrate node. I have generated the custom types and methods following https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/ as a guideline.

When I wish to use these derives, my editor properly autocompletes methods:
[image: Typescript autocomplete custom types]

However, when I attempt to access methods such as unwrap on the Option<> type following the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.basics/#working-with-optiontype), I get the following issue in my typescript compiler:

[image: Typescript complaints about Codec]

Does anyone have some hints as to why every return type from the ApiPromise is returning a base `Codec` instead of the desired type?

---

Other notes:

- The typegen docs example and scripts seem to be a bit out of date. I have an auto-generated `types-lookup.ts` file which has defined all of my custom types. I have tried exposing it in my `tsconfig.json` like so:

```
"@polkadot/types/lookup": [
    "packages/types/src/interfaces/types-lookup.ts"
],
"@polkadot/api/augment": ["packages/types/src/interfaces/augment-api.ts"],
"@polkadot/types/augment": ["packages/types/src/interfaces/augment-types.ts"],
```

Comment: The code in your question has some typo, try correct it first:
1. In the first screen shot, variable name is chainTree2
2. In the second screen shot, variable name is chainTree

Comment: Possibly caused by https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing for TS augmentation

Comment: Thank you Jaco, indeed I am encountering the issue described by your link. I am attempting to apply the types augmentation in our 'api' package before our 'options' export, but hitting separate TS compilation issues related to ESM configuration in the 'api' package and CJS configuration in our types package.


The FAQ docs mention: 'only the augmentation for the specific chain... should be imported'.  To be clear, I am assuming users of our api should only need an 'options' import from the 'api' package alone - and not an explicit import to our 'typegen' package?